# Bridging Thunderbolt Ethernet Connections

Tags: networking, network-bridge, thunderbolt

Can Ubuntu bridge ethernet (thunderbolt networking) connections/adapters?  The goal is to bridge two hosts each with a thunderbolt adapter; when you have one host, and you connect to host 2 and host 3 using thunderbolt, you should get two thunderbolt ethernet connections on the original host; can these two thunderbolt connections be bridged using Ubuntu? (on whatever kernel level is needed)

Thanks
LF

Comment: I take as no one has answered the question that Ubuntu does not support thunderbolt networking with ability to bridge the tb connections, thanks